# how to check given date is in range on table records

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql

This is the problem i can not solve:
I have one special index number on transactions tables and i reset this special index number every year.Here is the code.

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Index),0)+1 as Index_Number FROM Transactions WHERE YEAR(Create_Date) = '2016'
```

I have no problem with this query, its works fine.If we think that the dates of the recorded data are:

```
id | index | create_date
 1 |   7   |  2016-01-01
 2 |   8   |  2016-01-03
```

When data is entered in the date 2016-01-02, the index number of the id 2 must be 9. The index number of the newly added data must be 8.

In other words, the final state should be:

```
 id | index | create_date
  1 |   7   |  2016-01-01
  3 |   8   |  2016-01-02
  2 |   9   |  2016-01-03
```

How can I do this?

I have forgotten to mention that the index number varies according to each person so I can not use auto_increment.

Comment: why not to use auto_increment on "index" column ?

Comment: Can I build a structure that can be reset every year and can be sorted as I have mentioned above?

Comment: so after adding "2016-01-02" your index for the row "2016-01-03" sholud be changed?
If it is then you  have 2 approaches: one -  add rows with such step in index, that you will always be able to find index value that may be inserted; another is to perform 3 queries: find desired index (in our test case 8), shift all indexes >= 8, and finally insert new row.
But after your mention, suspect that "index" maybe not a number?

Comment: I would like to thank you for your reply, first of all, I am sure that "index" is definitely a number. I think I have the same solution but I have not figured out how to code them. For example, I do not understand how to find two dates and repeat all sequences, how can I tell if the date entered by the user is within the limits of any of the dates registered in the database? If we go according to the above example, the id number is 3.

Comment: Your column called `index` is something that colud be calculated in a query. It appears you just want a running count of rows within a year increasing in date/time order. In other databases you could use row_number () over () to do this. By the way calling a column `index` is not a great idea either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wrote "index" here to make it descriptive. Unfortunately I have to use mysql in this example.

Comment: I was trying to indicate this is a bad idea. Eg What happens if you need to recalculate 234567 rows?  Also research alternatives for row_number in mysql. Plus `index` is a reaerved word and not descriptive of the functional purpose of that column.

Comment: I strongly agree with what you say, but I do not think I will ever reach that number of lines so I'll just use it for a small project. I also wrote "index" for the understanding of the column, not the name "index".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example it should be something like this:

```
set @userinput = '2016-01-02';
set @i = (SELECT ifnull(min(index),1) FROM FROM Transactions WHERE YEAR(Create_Date) = '2016') and Create_Date > @userinput;
update  Transactions set index = index+1 WHERE YEAR(Create_Date) = '2016') and  index >= @i;
insert into Transactions (`index`,`Create_Date`) values (@i, @userinput);
```

so first you search min index for dates that greater then entered (for the certain year),

then you update all "index" for the rows with greater date but same year, shifting it

finally insert you new row

Comment: The code works exactly the way I want it to, thank you very much, but if the user does not have a date in the database it returns a null value. Is there a chance to integrate the code I used above (to calculate the "index" number) here? For example, if the user enters data on the date "2016-01-04", the "index" number is blankly recorded.

Comment: updated. you always can use "ifnull" function, alternately you can move it to insert ~ ifnull(@i,1)

Comment: What I'm talking about is that the record entered by the user (in this example, "2016-01-04") needs to be recalculated if it is not between two dates (such as "2016-01-02" in the query). In this case, using the initial query will solve the problem. Thank you again.